# Resources for TDD best practices, methods, etc

Tags: tdd

I'm looking for a good set of resources to get starting on converting to TDD, I always seem to start off with getting unit tests running at first but the more I develop the less I want to write tests for things that I know work. So I am looking to change my mindset and start developing with a TDD mindset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want *Test-Driven Development: By Example* by Kent Beck and *Refactoring* by Martin Fowler.  IMHO, they should be sold as a 2-volume set.  *TDD:BE* covers things largely from a the testing side, and shows you some refactoring techniques.  *Refactoring* covers things largely from the refactoring side, and brings up good testing practices.  Between the two of them, you should have all you need to get started.

Comment: As a third book, you could then go to "Refactoring to Patterns", by  Joshua Kerievsky...

Comment: I might have said "Clean Code", by Robert Martin.  Or maybe "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al - there are a lot of good add-ons to this list. But really, the two I mentioned are the core volumes in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

This book is good, and is very new (came out 2009).

**Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided By Tests**, by Freeman and Pryce
[image]
<sub>(source: [barnesandnoble.com](http://images.barnesandnoble.com/images/29240000/29249083.JPG))</sub>

---

This book came out in 2003, but it contains a *complete* example from start to finish.
**Test-driven development: A Practical Guide**, by Astels
[image]
<sub>(source: [barnesandnoble.com](http://images.barnesandnoble.com/images/17170000/17176564.JPG))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/)

Comment: Really like the book, but it is a .NET book. Beck's book has examples in Java, but most of the book is language agnostic, whereas this book has lots of language-specific considerations (ex which Mocking framework to pick).

Answer (score 1):

**Test Driven Development : By Example**, by Kent Beck
[image]
<sub>(source: [barnesandnoble.com](http://images.barnesandnoble.com/images/14580000/14587403.JPG))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nunit

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Two classics:

- [Test infected: programmers love
  writing tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/testinfected/testing.htm).
- [The bowling game episode](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/xpepisode.htm).